# In Haskell, is there a good way to write a num to num conversion function `toNum :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b`?

Tags: haskell, numbers, typeclass

For example, one bad way is to factor through a string:

```
toReadableNum :: (Num a, Num b, Read b) => a -> b
toReadableNum = read . show
```

If there are no good ways, are there other bad ways?  Implementation specific?  Requiring language extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't go (sanely) from `Num` to `Num`, as Num provides no mechanism for extracting information about the value held other than its spurious Eq and Show machinery, but if you are willing to assume a bit more on the behalf of the number you are coming from, then you can have recourse.

In particular

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

and the composition of

```
toRational :: Real a => a -> Rational
```

with

```
fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a
```

are both good candidates for doing what you mean, if not exactly what you asked for.

While `read . show` is well typed and has the signature you propose, the meaning is gobbledigook. There is nothing at all that says the text emitted by one `Show` instance will be compatible with a completely different `Read` instance, and there are plenty of counter examples.

The (implied) contract on `Read` and `Show` only apply when you use them with the same type!

Answer (score 7):

There are no good ways.  Some numbers contain more information that other, so how could you expect to convert between two arbitrary numbers in a good way.  Some simple examples: How do you convert a Double to an Int?  A Rational to on Int8?  A Complex Double to a Float?

All this involve information loss and then there is no obvious right way.

---

And as @hammar says, the operations in `Num` simply don't allow you to construct such a function.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write any useful function of the type `(Num a, Num b) => a -> b`. Since `a` and `b` are type variables, the only useful operations we can use on them are the ones in the `Num` class. (`Eq` and `Show` won't help us much here).

```
class  (Eq a, Show a) => Num a  where
    (+), (-), (*)       :: a -> a -> a
    negate              :: a -> a
    abs                 :: a -> a
    signum              :: a -> a
    fromInteger         :: Integer -> a
```

The only function here that allows you to make an `b` if you didn't have one to start with is `fromInteger`, but you have no way of turning `a` into an `Integer`, so the only functions you can write of this type return `fromInteger` of some constant, or bottom. Not very useful.

---

As [augustss pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798808/in-haskell-is-there-a-good-way-to-write-a-num-to-num-conversion-function-tonum/6798961#6798961), there is no obvious way of making this conversion anyway. Remember lots of types can be `Num`. Not only the various types of real numbers, but also complex numbers, matrices, polynomials, etc. There is no meaningful conversion that would work between all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The good way is to make specific kind of conversion, like round or clamp. Such function does what it say it does.